# Why can I not Loop Cut my plane?

Tags: geometry, loop

Why can I not Loop Cut my plane?

[image]

The yellow dots appear on the side... I just don't understand it.

I guess it can only be really understood with the blend file, so I have uploaded it here:

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Loop cuts do not work on n-gons (polygons with more than 4 vertices).

When I switched to Vertex Selection Mode there were some vertices on the sides.

[image]

After I removed them using *Dissolve Vertices*, *Loop Cutting* worked as expected.